# How do I decrease the connect timeout with Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I want to make a database connection to my SQL Server fail fast. How can I decrease the timeout? I've tried adding `Connection Timeout=1` in my connection string, however this doesn't seem to make a difference.

With `Connection Timeout=500`, it takes about 8 min 30 seconds to timeout. This is expected. With `Connection Timeout=1`, it takes around 40 seconds to timeout which is way longer than expected.

I found the `EntityConnection.ConnectionTimeout` property but it is read only. Is there anything else I can do to decrease this timeout? Is this an issue with Entity?

**UPDATE:** Here is my connect string. It still takes ~40 seconds to timeout.

```
<add name="KofaxAdminToolsEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DB.Model.KofaxAdminTools.csdl|res://*/DB.Model.KofaxAdminTools.ssdl|res://*/DB.Model.KofaxAdminTools.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MY_DATASOURCE;initial catalog=MY_CATALOG;persist security info=True;user id=MY_USER;password=MY_PASSWORD;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;Connection Timeout=1&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

**UPDATE 2:** So I discovered that the timeout was a **tcp timeout**, not a **sql connect timeout**. If my machine were able to reach the host, @marc_s solution would have worked, however, since I cannot reach that host, the tcp timeout comes into play. Does anyone know how to decrease the tcp timeout for a `SqlConnection`?

Comment: You could specify it in the connectionstring

Comment: Could you please post your connection string?

Comment: Your Update 2 is correct. On my local dev I have an Alias defined (using TCP). Connection string timeout works but takes longer than whatever you set in connection string when I hit the server using alias. If I change Data Source name to actual name (not the alias) then the Connection Timeout=1 works as expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Where and how did you specify that connection timeout?

I just tried and added this to my EF connection string (using EF database-first) - and it works as expected: with SQL Server service stopped, the connection attempts time out almost immediately....

```
<add name="myEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/People.csdl|res://*/People.ssdl|res://*/People.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
             provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=mydb;
             integrated security=True;connect timeout=1;multipleactiveresultsets=True;
                                      ***************** 
             App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

(*EF connection string broken up and wrapped for clarity - this will be just one long line in your `web.config`*)

You need to add `connect timeout=x` (where `x` is in seconds, any value bigger than 0 is ok) **inside** the `provider connection string=` value of your EF connection string.

Comment: What does the `multipleactiveresultsets` entry do? Also, what kind of database are you connecting to with this app.config?

Comment: @Brandon: this is for SQL Server (2005 or newer). The `multipleactiveresultsets` is optional - it allows multiple `SqlDataReader` connections at the same time

Comment: I happen to be working with Blaine on this question and know that he is hitting an MS SQL Express 2005 server...would this make a difference at all?

Comment: @Brandon: no, not in this regard. The connection strings and their options are almost identical between Express and other editions of SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code in the constructor of your DbContext class:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 1;
```

Comment: That's the **command timeout** - the time span a running command can use up before it times out. This has **NOTHING** to do with the **connection timeout** (the max. time allowed for the **connection** to the database to be opened)

Comment: How about a web.config setting?  Something that can be changed without a full recompile and publish.